# Aggregating values in the list [[ "a" x ][ "a" y ]] to be [ "a" (x + y) ]

Tags: netlogo

---

If I have a list like this:

```
let m [["a" 1]["a" 5]["b" 3]["b" 7]["c" 1]]
```

What is the proper syntax to produce `[["a" 6]["b" 10]["c" 1]]`?

I have tried this but I always got `ERROR: Expected a variable name here`.

```
reduce [[[x y ][ x z ]] -> [ x y + z ]] m
```

Thank you.

Comment: I can't see any way to do this with `reduce` because you need it to choose whether to create a separate item (if the "a", "b" etc not yet occurs) or add. You would likely need to either use the table extension or construct a list of the unique first elements and then iterate through those with `foreach`

Comment: the table extension unfortunately does not accept multi-key input. So after you input `table:put <table_name> "a" 5` after `"a" 1` it will overwrite the former.

I am so sorry but I have no idea how to construct a list of the unique value like you said or iterate through them. I think it sounds like the solution though.

Comment: table extension does accept multi-key input I believe, try the `table:from-list`. But if you want a `foreach` solution, please make an attempt first so we have something to work from

Comment: I have tried the `table:from-list` . I run `show table:from-list m` and it showed `{{table: [["a" 5] ["b" 7] ["c" 1]]}}` only. For the `foreach` procedure I could not think of the way to do double loop in NetLogo as I've tried for example `
foreach m [x -> foreach x [[a b] -> show (word a "is not" b)]]` which still cause error.

Could it be completed with `map`? I have tried `show (map [ [a b][a c] -> [a (b + c)] ] m)` but it highlights the first `c` and says 'Expected closing bracket'.

Comment: Hi @JenB sorry if I bother you but I just would like to inform an update about the unique first elements of the list. I have been able to produce that using ```to-report listoflist_rmdup [li]
  let unique-li []
  foreach li [? -> set unique-li lput item 0 ? unique-li]
  report remove-duplicates unique-li
end``` and then just ```show listoflist_rmdup m```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you did your foreach attempt as an answer instead of editing your question. It looks like you solved it, well done. But I thought I should provide a version using the same logic but with the new list syntax. You are using v5 and the list syntax changed substantially in v6. I also used `first` and other similar keywords for readability.

This is a standalone model, you can put it in an empty NetLogo session and run the 'testme' procedure to see how it works.

```
to testme
  let m [["a" 1]["a" 5]["b" 2]["c" 5]["b" 3]["b" 7]["c" 1]]
  print m
  print aggregate-lol m
end

to-report aggregate-lol [#li]
  ; sort the list alphabetically on first of pair
  let the-list sort-by [[a b] -> first a < first b] #li
  ; prime the loop
  let now-letter first first the-list
  let add-pair first the-list
  let result []
  ; loop from the second item to the end
  foreach butfirst the-list
  [ this-pair ->
    ifelse first this-pair = now-letter
    ; in same group so add
    [ set add-pair (list first add-pair (last add-pair + last this-pair)) ]
    ; in different group so output and use this item as start of next group
    [ set result lput add-pair result
      set add-pair this-pair
      set now-letter first this-pair
    ]
  ]
  ; append the final pair
  set result lput add-pair result
  
  report result
end
```

It will also work simply by typing something like `print aggregate-lol [["a" 1]["a" 5]["b" 2]["c" 5]["b" 3]["b" 7]["c" 1]]` in the command center.

Here is an alternative (dense code and fairly unreadable) that uses the efficient list primitives. Note that `map` essentially does the job of the `foreach` in the original construction by applying a function to every item in a given list and constructing a list from the results. The `filter` selects the needed list items (that match the first letter).

```
to-report aggregate-dense [#li]
  ; list of unique first letters
  let all-firsts remove-duplicates map [ll -> first ll] #li
  ; by first letters, filter, sum and construct pair into list
  report map [ ff ->
    (list ff sum map [ll -> last ll] filter [ii -> first ii = ff] #li)
  ] all-firsts
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't appreciate you more for providing your version as well. It is more compact and does make much more sense. The reason I did not edit my question anymore because to me I have the exact solution for my own problem, although it is still a bit rough. Also, to be honest I'm not sure that I understand what you meant by 'v5 ' and 'v6'.

Comment: I would also like to point out some minor suggestion on the first version of your code that personally I think is quicker to grasp: swapping `now-letter` and `add-pair` so it will become `let add-pair first the-list   let now-letter first add-pair`.

Comment: v5 and v6 are NetLogo versions. NetLogo updated to version 6 a couple of years ago, but you are still using version 5

Comment: Actually I made the code in the latest version of NetLogo available at the moment (6.1.1)

Comment: The code you have will not work after v5 because the ? syntax for lists is obsolete. You my have two versions installed, but the code you wrote will not work in v6.1.1

Comment: Oh, if that what you meant I just use that question mark as the anonymous variable, notice the arrow I put after ```foreach (range 1 li-length)``` . As a matter of fact I did try that code in my own 6.1.1. I apologize that I caused confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: @JenB made a revised, more clear version as response of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037738/13414459) and has been accepted as the final answer.

The MVP (most valuable procedure) here is `item` because the list also contains list.

In order to obtain the intended list, these are necessary points to do:

1. sort the list of list in alphabetical order ()
2. sum the value based on the letter.

To do the first point:

```
globals [the_list]

set the_list report sort-by [[a b] -> item 0 a < item 0 b] m
```

And the second point:

```
to-report aggregate-lol [li]
  let result []
  let first_item item 0 li     ; first_item is also a list
  let li-length length li
  let li-end li-length - 1
  foreach (range 1 li-length)
  [ ? -> ifelse ? != li-end
    [ ifelse item 0 item ? li = item 0 first_item
      [ set first_item replace-item 1 first_item (item 1 first_item + item 1 item ? li) ]
      [ set result lput first_item result
        set first_item item ? li ]
    ]
    [ ifelse item 0 item ? li = item 0 first_item
      [ set first_item replace-item 1 first_item (item 1 first_item + item 1 item ? li)
        set result lput first_item result ]
      [ set result lput first_item result
        set result lput item li-end li result ]
    ]
  ]
  report result
end
```

So the result will be

```
show aggregate-lol the_list
```